# apple push notification review

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications

I am implementing APN's and want to release without switching it on yet..

So the app will happily receive them. but we will choose not to send them until later.

My question is, as when we want to send notifications is in our control, do apple care about this when reviewing the app.

I thinking not, maybe they send a test notification to the device to prove it works?  but if anyone has any experience in dealing with this any info would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Apple does not test the notifications during the review.
They doesn't register to notifications at the first launch of apps.